# How to disable HTML paste in Microsoft Office Communicator

Tags: office-communicator-2007

When I copy from my browser and paste into Microsoft Office Communicator, frequently the result is grossly disruptive: the contents of a text area will cause the chat to scroll off the page, or the exact fonts and colors will be reproduced.

The current workaround is to paste first to SlickEdit, then copy from SlickEdit and paste to MOC.

Is there a better way?

Comment: i have to do something similar to remove formatting in openoffice pastes on the linux side...it does seem like there should be an option to do this

Comment: I dont think there is any such configuration available in OC.nor does it have any xmls to configure.[w.r.t version 3.5]

Answer (score 6):

http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/

> PureText is basically equivalent to opening Notepad, doing a PASTE, followed by a SELECT-ALL, and then a COPY.  The benefit of PureText is performing all these actions with a single Hot-Key and having the result pasted into the current window automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the link to PureText.  Policies at my worksite sharply restrict the deployment of third-party utilities.  Perhaps I can encourage the watchdogs to put this on the "blessed" list.

Answer (score 4):

From [Rich Content and HTML in Instant Messages](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lync/archive/2009/03/04/rich-content-and-html-in-instant-messages.aspx#241774):

Add a 32-bit DWORD key `DisableHTMLIM`, value `1`
at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator`

Then restart MOC.

Answer (score 1):

In some software the shortcut key`control-shift-v` is 'paste as text'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 does not appear to abide by this convention.

Comment: @ThomasLHoladay That's right. Microsoft thought this would be a fine keyboard shortcut to start a voice call, when you're trying to paste basic text to your manager...